IB HL Math AA Paper 3 Question (Reduction Formula & Definite Integrals)
I spotted a question in my IB textbook recently and came across this question that explores the reduction formula and definite integrals:
Let $I_n = \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-n} dx$.
By expressing $(1+x^2)^{-n}$ as $(1+x^2)^{-n} (1)$, or otherwise, show that
$$I_{n+1} = (1-\frac{1}{2n})I_n+\frac{2^{-n-1}}{n}$$ for $n\ge1$.
What I have initially tried to do is integrating by parts, letting $u=(1+x^2)^{-n-1}$ and $dv=dx$, then $du=(2x)(-n-1)(1+x^2)^{-n-2}dx$ and $v=x$:
$$I_{n+1} = \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-n-1}(1)dx$$
$$=[x(1+x^2)^{-n-1}]_0^1+(n+1)\int_0^1 2x^2(1+x^2)^{-n-2}dx$$
$$=2^{-n-1}+(n+1)\int_0^1 2x^2(1+x^2)^{-n-2}dx$$
So I am able to get a $2^{-n-1}$ term but am unable to solve the integral that follows after. Anyone has any thoughts on this?

Hint: don’t start with $I_{n+1}$. Just do integration by parts, in the way you have already, but starting with $I_{n}$.  It all works out fine.

Well done! Please remove your solution from your question and post it as an answer.

$x=\tan\theta$ substitution is another way.

Solution:
By finding $I_n$ in terms of $I_{n+1}$.
$$I_n = \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^n(1)dx$$
$$I_{n+1} = \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-n-1}dx$$
Let $u=(1+x^2)^{-n}$ and $dv=dx$, then $du=-2nx(1+x^2)^{-n-1}dx$ and $v=x$.
Then
$$I_n=uv-\int vdu$$
$$=[x(1+x^2)^{-n}]_0^1 + 2n \int_0^1 x^2 (1+x^2)^{-n-1}dx$$
$$=2^{-n} + 2n \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-n-1}[(1+x^2)-1]dx$$
$$=2^{-n} + 2n [\int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-n}dx-\int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-n-1}dx]$$
We then notice that
$$I_n=2^{-n} + 2n I_n - 2n I_{n+1}$$
Making $I_{n+1}$ the subject,
$$2n I_{n+1}=2n I_n - I_n + 2^{-n}$$
Dividing by $2n$ on both sides,
$$I_{n+1}=I_n - \frac{I_n}{2n} + \frac{2^{-n-1}}{n}$$
$$I_{n+1}=(1-\frac{1}{2n})I_n + \frac{2^{-n-1}}{n} (shown)$$
